# Facebook Dialog vs Open Graph Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Just want to understand the pros and cons of making post through dialog vs open graph action for the first facebook app I am making.

The most attractive aspect of OG action post seems to be the "aggregate" box if I can attract users to use my app frequently and consistently, but dialog seems to guarantee 100% chance for the post to show up individually on the user's timeline (vs OG action post which might only show in the "recent activity" box which is not obvious to see...)

am I missing reasons why OG Actions seems to be what facebook is pushing (and slowly dying out dialogs?)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dialogs are not going away at all, but they can only represent one kind of action in your app.

Open Graph lets you represent N number of actions in your app, for example, listening to a song, staring/liking a song, adding a song to a play list, etc.

You clearly wouldn't want to use a dialog to share all those actions to a user's timeline.

For simple sharing of some item, use a dialog, but anything else, use OG.

Comment: thanks Douglas, but I can always tweak the wordings in og:description and og:title to create the feel of customized action/objects right? From my (limited) understanding, dialogs always get posted individually on timeline but OG action might or might not (it seems that those which users input comments before posting always show (like when i comment on pinterest) otherwise they get hid away in the "recent activities" box), is that correct? since developers want posts to appear prominently on timeline, what's the incentive for them to use OG Action? that's the part that I am not understanding.