# feed dialog vs explicit sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, feed

What are the pros and cons of using feed dialog vs explicit open graph sharing? They seem to be doing more or less the same thing - posting a news story on the user's timeline, and potentially  his friends' news feeds. 
Feed dialog is more intrusive in the sense that it has a facebook popup window. Aside from that, is there a difference in how facebook displays/prioritizes the two?

Comment: here is a similar question with some good insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716892/facebook-dialog-vs-open-graph-action

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is how it fits within your user journey.

Feed dialog does not require the user to have installed your application at all, while the Open Graph solution requires your user to have installed your application and to also have given extended permission, therefore two popup dialogs, with a typical dropoff of around 50%.

Does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why it is that the vast majority of apps that want me to share a story take the graphAPI approach? What are the benefits that make it worth forcing me to extend permissions?

Maybe they're counting on the fact that if I'm willing to jump through hoops the first time I'll be more likely to share stories in the future and/or allow them to post on my behalf.